# Name of a specific graph with fixed distance and degree

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology, extremal-graph-theory

I was trying to come up with a graph that maximizes the number of nodes such that there exists a path between any two nodes that is length 2, and the degree of each node is 10. Then I tried to generalize the result and failed and now I want to learn if there is a graph type with for every two nodes there exists a path of length k that connects them and the degree of each node is equal to n.
Is there a theory behind this class of graphs?

Comment: This is very close to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296781/r-regular-graph-with-diameter-2 – also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745954/how-to-construct-a-5-regular-graph-with-diameter-2-on-22-vertices is related

Comment: Have you followed those links?

Comment: Yes, I have, and thank you for the guidance. What I have found in the end is this Wikipedia website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_the_largest_known_graphs_of_a_given_diameter_and_maximal_degree which kind of finalized my search.

Comment: If you found something that enables you to answer your question, let me encourage you to write up what you have found, and to post it as an answer.